# ARIMA model with nonlinear exogenous variable in R

Tags: r, time-series, regression, non-linear-regression

I'm doing a non-linear regression in R and want to add one moving-average term to my model to eliminate the autocorrelations in residuals.

Basically, here is the model:

```
y[n] = a + log((x1[n])^g + (x2[n])^g) + c*e[n-1] + e[n]
```

where `[e]` is the moving average term.

I plan to use `ARIMA(0, 0, 1)` to model residuals. However, I do not know which function I should use in R to add non-linear exogenous part to ARIMA model.

More information: I know how to use `nls` command to estimate `a` and `g`, but do not know how to deal with `e[n]`.

I know that `xreg` in `arima` can handle ARIMA model with linear exogenous variables. Is there a similar function to handle ARIMA model with nonlinear exogenous variables?

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Hi Zheyuan, thank you for the suggestion. But I need to model residuals instead of adding fixed effects. Can "nlme" handle ARIMA(0,0,1) model with nonlinear exogenous part? Could you please explain more? Thank you again.

Comment: OK, thank you very much! I will try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nlme` has such capability, as it is fitting non-linear mixed models. You can think of it an extension to `nls` (a fixed-effect only non-linear regression), by allowing random effect and correlated errors.

`nlme` can handle ARMA correlation, by something like `correlation = corARMA(0.2, ~ 1, p = 0, q = 1, fixed = TRUE)`. This means, that residuals are MA(1) process, with initial guess of coefficient 0.2, but to be updated during model fitting. The `~ 1` suggests that `MA(1)` is on intercept and there is no further grouping structure.

I am not an expert in `nlme`, but I know `nlme` is what you need. I produce the following example, but since I am not an expert, I can't get `nlme` work at the moment. I post it here to give a start / flavour.

```
set.seed(0)
x1 <- runif(100)
x2 <- runif(100)
## MA(1) correlated error, with innovation standard deviation 0.1
e <- arima.sim(model = list(ma = 0.5), n = 100, sd = 0.1)
## a true model, with `a = 0.2, g = 0.5`
y0 <- 0.2 + log(x1 ^ 0.5 + x2 ^ 0.5)
## observations
y <- y0 + e

## no need to install; it comes with R; just `library()` it
library(nlme)

fit <- nlme(y ~ a + log(x1 ^ g + x2 ^ g), fixed = a + g ~ 1,
            start = list(a = 0.5, g = 1),
            correlation = corARMA(0.2, form = ~ 1, p = 0, q = 1, fixed = FALSE))
```

Similar to `nls`, we have an overall model formula `y ~ a + log(x1 ^ g + x2 ^ g)`, and starting values are required for iteration process. I have chosen `start = list(a = 0.5, g = 1)`. The `correlation` bit has been explained in the beginning.

`fixed` and `random` arguments in `nlme` specify what should be seen as fixed effects and random effects in the overall formula. Since we have no random effect, we leave it unspecified. We want `a` and `g` as fixed effect, so I tried something like `fixed = a + g ~ 1`. Unfortunately it does not quite work, for some reason I don't know. I read the `?nlme`, and thought this formula means that we want a common `a` and `g` for all observations, but later `nlme` reports an error saying this is not a valid group formula.

I am also investing at this; as I said, the above gives us a start. We are already fairly close to the final answer.

---

Thanks to [user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650) for point out my awkward error. I should use `gnls` function rather than `nlme`. By design nature of `nlme` package, functions `lme` and `nlme` have to take a `random` argument to work. Luckily, there are several other routines in `nlme` package for extending linear models and non-linear models.

- `gls` and `gnls` extend `lm` and `nls` by allowing non-diagonal variance functions.

So, I should really use `gnls` instead:

```
## no `fixed` argument as `gnls` is a fixed-effect only
fit <- gnls(y ~ a + log(x1 ^ g + x2 ^ g), start = list(a = 0.5, g = 1),
            correlation = corARMA(0.2, form = ~ 1, p = 0, q = 1, fixed = FALSE))

#Generalized nonlinear least squares fit
#  Model: y ~ a + log(x1^g + x2^g) 
#  Data: NULL 
#  Log-likelihood: 92.44078
#
#Coefficients:
#        a         g 
#0.1915396 0.5007640 
#
#Correlation Structure: ARMA(0,1)
# Formula: ~1 
# Parameter estimate(s):
#   Theta1 
#0.4184961 
#Degrees of freedom: 100 total; 98 residual
#Residual standard error: 0.1050295
```

Comment: your welcome. You might like the Pinheiro&Bates mixed-model book - free copy floating in the www , but i assume your dept will have a copy

Comment: I have tried.. but I need 15 reputation in order to "like" it (I only have 14 now). But of course, when I reach 15 reputation I will go back and accept your answer :)

Comment: Sorry I got a stupid question: why the ACF&PACF plots of residuals do not change after adding "correlation" command? They look exactly the same as the one produced by "nls". And even if I change ARMA(0,1) model to ARMA(1,0), the plots still remain unchanged. Basically, I extract the residuals using residuals() command. The numerical values changed, but not the autocorrelations...

Comment: Thank you for the rapid reply. I see :)

Comment: Thank you! You are really helpful :)

Comment: Hi Zheyuan, as I reviewed the help page of `gnls`, I found that `MA(1)` is not modelled simultaneously with the nonlinear part. The algorithm is: get residuals first; then model the residuals. So it makes no difference if I use `nls` to get residuals first and then use `arima()` to model it. Essentially, it is a 2-stage estimation and will make the `MA(1)` parameter biased.

Comment: @zy.G; what residuals are you using. If you are using the `raw` residuals they will not change. Use the `normalized`. have a read of `?residuals.gnls` [ `par(mfrow=c(2,1)) ; acf(resid(fit)) ; acf(resid(fit, type="normalized"))` ]

Comment: @user20650 thank you for the reply. I used `residuals` command so I guess it returns me raw residuals. But my confusion is whether the residuals are modelled simultaneously with the main non-linear function; or it's modelling after the stage 1 modelling is done. I will check the command you suggested. Thanks again.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thank you for the explanation. I will take another careful look at it :)

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Yes you are right.. The results are different. So the residuals are modelled with the main part simultaneously. Thanks!